# Consume REST web service from Swift client

Tags: web-services, rest, swift

I built a REST WS using dot net 4.5. When I verified it using the Chrome app Advanced Rest Client I get
 request: http://mySite.azurewebsites.net/api/tech
with GET selected

The tool reports a status code of 200 and a JSON response of:
[{"fName":"Fred","lName":"Flintstone"},{"fName":"Barney","lName":"Rubble"}]

Over in XCode, using Swift I try a button that calls hitMyWS():

```
func hitMyWS(){

    var url : String = "http://mySite.azurewebsites.net/api/Tech"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            // process jsonResult
            println("it worked")
        } else {
            // couldn't load JSON, look at error
            println("kablooey")
        }


    })    }
```

In the console I get "kablooey"

This is my first attempt at REST web services and Swift, please advise.

Comment: Have you verified that no authorization is required by the WS?

Comment: In addition, you should first of all check whether `sendAsynchronousResult` gave an error (via it's `error` parameter, you you declared over...). You should also check what's in the `data` parameter. If both of these are fine, you should check whether the data is actually parseable into a NSDictionary.

Comment: @trig, I did a println(data) and got the hex. This converted to what I expected from my WS. It appears that my WS's return is indeed not parseable into a NSDictionary. Thanks!

Comment: Well I am just guessing here, your JSON Looks like an Array of Dictionaries, should you nötig expect to pause it like that?